# How to capture featureDeleted() info in PyQGIS3

Tags: layers, pyqgis-3, events, pyqt5, signal

I have a system of scratch layers generated from table data in QGIS. Users may interact with the attribute tables directly (not good practice, but I did not design the system) or through a PyQt5 UI. Either way, changes made locally in the scratch layers must be captured and propagated to the database.

I have connected to the `featuresDeleted` signal as follows:

```
def connect_layer_loggers(self, lyr):
    if lyr == self.target_layer:  
        lyr.featuresDeleted.connect(self.log_target_feature_deleted)
        # other layers similarly connected

def log_target_feature_deleted(self, feat_id):
    if type(feat_id) == int: # Sometimes it is a list, sometimes an int
        feat_id = [feat_id]
    for fid in feat_id:
        target_feat = self.target_layer.getFeature(fid)
        seg_id = target_feat.attribute("id_pg")
        # do more stuff...
    QApplication.beep()
```

I have several issues:

1. When deleting a record using Edit mode in the Attributes table for the layer, the signal fires and runs the code; however, the feature has no attributes (presumably because it has been deleted, even though the deletion has not been committed) so `target_feat.attribute("id_pg")` causes an exception.
2. Curiously, when I cancel the changes, the `featuresDeleted` event is triggered again and this time, the feature *is* returned by the `getFeature(fid)` and code that should have run when *actually* deleting the record is now run, even though I have cancelled the deletion.
3. When a record is deleted in code `self.renderer.target_layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(target_fids)`
   the event is not triggered at all.

I have tried adding a @pyqtSlot() decorator, but I get a "Decorated slot has no compatible signature" error. `feat_id` can either be a list or an int depending on how the event is triggered. Neither arg type works in the decorator.

The documentation for the `featureDeleted` and `featuresDeleted` signals is not very helpful to me.

How do I properly connect/capture a signal so that I can perform a background database operation on the affected record when a record is added, deleted, or modified either from code or from direct table manipulation?

UPDATE:
Adding `self.renderer.target_layer.startEditing()` got the triggers to fire. The data that I wanted to capture from the deleted feature is still gone, unfortunately.

Comment: Not sure how to solve this apart from keeping a mapping of feature ID to "id_pg" elsewhere. It seems weird to try to access a deleted feature after deletion through this.

Comment: Deleting via the data provider bypasses the layer (and is rarely a good idea!), thus the layer does not know that the signal should be fired.

Comment: @bugmenot123 - I will check into removing the dataProvider object and see if the signal fires. With regard to the "id_pg" error, there is no info to glean from the deleted record. I hoped to capture the feature data in a beforeCommitChanges signal so to perform a db operation after, but it did not trigger, either. A direct connection to the db would be preferrable, but it is not a local server and it is WAY too slow. I have to read the db into a scratch layer, do local manipulations, then when all is done, any changes made must be written to the remote database.